# Структура базы для графика работ учереждений

Tags: база-данных, проектирование, sql-server

Пытаюсь спроектировать базу для хранения данных графика работ учереждений (магазинов, аптек и т.п.) Допустим есть аптека:

1. В будние дни работает с 9-18
2. С 13-14 обед
3. Суббота 9-17, Воскресенье выходной
4. Последний четверг месяца - санитарный день
5. 8-марта выходной

Соответственно нужно всю эту информацию внести в СУБД, сформировать некий запрос, который позволит узнать работает ли в данное время учереждение. Пытался сделать уже несколько схем, даже дошел до битовых масок с разбитием на получасовые промежутки по часам дня, но все получается достаточно сложно, а хочется красивого решения. Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей.

Comment: думаю, подобную логику куда проще организовать на сервере приложения, нежели в базе данных. В принципе, в базе данных имеет смысл хранить разве что список праздников (возможно, что он может пополниться чем-то еще помимо 8 марта, будь то Новый Год или День Албанской Авиации)

Comment: А на сервере в какой виде хранить? Тут я привел лишь пример какой сложности может быть режим работы одного учереждения. Я не могу понять по какому принципу таблицы создать и связать их в СУБД.

Answer (score 4):

Представляется удобным такой вариант, ну по крайней мере, решающий задачу:

```
create table calendar (
  month int,       -- месяц
  week int,        -- неделя в году
  weekofmonth int, -- неделя в месяце
  day int,         -- день в месяце
  dayofweek int,   -- день недели
  _start time,     -- время начала
  _end time,       -- время окончания
  work tinyint(1), -- работаем/не работаем
  comment text     -- комментарий
);
```

ну то есть все варианты, по которым возможно идентифицировать период заносим в такую структуру.

```
insert into calendar values 
--   m    w    wom  d    dow  start      end        [x]  cmnt
    (3   ,null,null,   8,null,      null,      null,0   ,"8-е марта"),
    (null,null,null,null,   1,'09:00:00','17:59:59',1   ,"пн"),
    (null,null,null,null,   2,'09:00:00','17:59:59',1   ,"вт"),
    (null,null,null,null,   3,'09:00:00','17:59:59',1   ,"ср"),
    (null,null,null,null,   4,'09:00:00','17:59:59',1   ,"чт"),
    (null,null,null,null,   5,'09:00:00','17:59:59',1   ,"пт"),
    (null,null,null,null,   6,'09:00:00','16:59:59',1   ,"сб"),
    (null,null,null,null,   7,'00:00:00','23:59:59',0   ,"вс"),
    (null,null,   4,null,   4,'00:00:00','23:59:59',0   ,"сан. день"),
    (null,null,null,null,null,'13:00:00','13:59:59',0   ,"обед");
```

Дальше подставляем для каждой такой строки нашу дату.

```
select 
 c.work, 
 c.comment
from (SELECT $date as d) cd 
 join calendar c
on  (WEEK(cd.d) = c.week or c.week is NULL)
and (MONTH(cd.d) = c.month or c.month is NULL)
and (c.weekofmonth = (WEEK(cd.d)-WEEK(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(cd.d,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)),INTERVAL 1 DAY))+1) or c.weekofmonth is NULL)
and (DAY(cd.d) = c.day or c.day is NULL)
and (TIME(cd.d) between c._start and c._end or c._start is NULL or c._end is NULL)
and (MOD((DAYOFWEEK(cd.d)+5),7)+1 = c.dayofweek or c.dayofweek is NULL);
```

Если выборка пустая, значит не работаем. Если не пустая и есть хотя бы одна запись с work=0 - не работаем. В остальных случаях (когда есть записи только с work=1) работаем.

Да, с weekofmonth пришлось извращаться, возможно можно проще.
При желании можно оформить этот запрос в виде UDF.
При желании/необходимости можно таблицу декомпозировать, но имхо и так нормально...

Как альтернатива генерить на год по записи на день интервал работы

```
create table calendar (
  workstart datetime,
  workend datetime
);

select count(*) from calendar where $date between workstart and workend;
```

при заполнении дробить интервал на обед.

ЗЫ черт, только что заметил, что речь об mssql, а написал уже для mysql. Для mssql все аналогично, только функции получения частей даты там немного другие, думаю, ничего же страшного, да? главное ведь идея ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Видимо действительно, какое-то элегантное решение так с ходу и не сообразить. Мы пока остановились на похожем варианте. Создали относительно универсальную таблицу для правил работы, а потом на месяц вперед заполняем на каждый день. Посмотрим как сработает.

Comment: @Vasya_P, Заполнять график работы на период - нормальная практика. В 1с, например, графики работы заполняют на год, с учетом праздников и переносов (там время работы не нужно, правда). Если такая таблица календаря будет участвовать в каких-либо расчетах, так вообще удобно - расчет почти полностью идет в sql.  
С другой стороны "работаем мы в данный момент или нет" не самый частый юзкейс, тут возможны любые варианты в принципе, в том числе битовые маски, о которых вы упоминали...